Zoom revoke token request returns invalid client error
I have a website that lets you connect a zoom account and I want to revoke the token when the account is disconnected this is my revoke function:
func revokeZoomAccount(token *oauth2.Token, dp dataprovider.Provider) (err *utils.Error) {
    revokeUrl := "https://zoom.us/oauth/revoke"
    // Create client with the token
    client := ZoomOAuthConfig.Client(context.Background(), token)

    // Prepare the form data (URL-encoded)
    formData := url.Values{}
    formData.Set("token", token.AccessToken) // Assuming token.AccessToken is the actual token string

    // Create the request
    req, rErr := http.NewRequest("POST", revokeUrl, strings.NewReader(formData.Encode()))
    if rErr != nil {
        return &utils.Error{Code: http.StatusInternalServerError, Message: "failed to create request"}
    }

    // Set the headers
    clientId, _ := os.LookupEnv(env.ZoomClientId)
    clientSecret, _ := os.LookupEnv(env.ZoomClientSecret)
    auth := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(clientId + ":" + clientSecret))
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Basic "+auth)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    resp, rErr := client.Do(req)
    if rErr != nil {
        err = &utils.Error{Code: http.StatusInternalServerError,
            Message: rErr.Error(),
        }
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    var responseBody map[string]interface{}
    json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&responseBody)
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        err = &utils.Error{Code: http.StatusInternalServerError, Message: "failed to revoke token"}
    }
    return
}

the problem is I am getting response 400 invalid client I checked my clientId and client secret and they are correct do you have any idea?
